# Magento 2.3.4 it's not working properly in my localhost

Tags: magento, installation

I have installed Magento 2.3.4 in my localhost and it's a successfully installed. But When I open Home page it shows some components of the main page like header,Logo and footer but the main body contain this phrase "CMS homepage content goes here." and doesn't show nothing. In spite of The admin Dashbord work correctly after a ceveral changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Orw3.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI0zl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is very normal**, It is working and there is no issue, as you are running a **vanilla magento** (fresh install with empty data) .

You can **edit/build the home page** in Admin menu : 
Content > elements > Pages, and then choose home page.

If you are just testing magento and need sample data, including sample homepage, then follow the steps here : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html